# React Native, I don't know why it's cannot show me information, I can got data but just not show to me

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

React Native, I don't know why it's cannot show me information, I can got data but just not show to me.

When I check log, it was got data, but I don't know why just cannot show to me.

in my code,

```
export default function Categories(categoryList) {
  console.log("=============>>>>>", categoryList);
  return (
    <View className="mt-3">
      <Text className="font-bold text-[20px]">Categories</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={categoryList}
        numColumns={4}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center  p-2 border-[1px] border-gray-300 m-1 h-[80px] rounded-lg">
            <Image source={{ uri: item.icon }} className="w-[40px] h-[40px]" />
            <Text className="text-[12px]">{item.name}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

And this is log.

```
 LOG  =============>>>>> {"categoryList": [{"icon": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSN2-1V6diClBPxDfdbemCZ-YZdBZ2sctV4-A&usqp=CAU", "name": "Pork"}, {"icon": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTL_90y045ZwtaL_8blhj1Yu8t-xrntETuuhUAlLIaO9bKssbu5LXiTaPOKVLxa6YV4wSk&usqp=CAU", "name": "Wagyu"}, {"icon": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQtNk7qbfHVbJkIrde4DFhTj7-acZupS0BMmA&usqp=CAU", "name": "Lamb"}]}
 LOG  =============>>>>> {"categoryList": [{"icon": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSN2-1V6diClBPxDfdbemCZ-YZdBZ2sctV4-A&usqp=CAU", "name": "Pork"}, {"icon": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTL_90y045ZwtaL_8blhj1Yu8t-xrntETuuhUAlLIaO9bKssbu5LXiTaPOKVLxa6YV4wSk&usqp=CAU", "name": "Wagyu"}, {"icon": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQtNk7qbfHVbJkIrde4DFhTj7-acZupS0BMmA&usqp=CAU", "name": "Lamb"}]}
 LOG  =============>>>>> {"categoryList": [{"icon": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSN2-1V6diClBPxDfdbemCZ-YZdBZ2sctV4-A&usqp=CAU", "name": "Pork"}, {"icon": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTL_90y045ZwtaL_8blhj1Yu8t-xrntETuuhUAlLIaO9bKssbu5LXiTaPOKVLxa6YV4wSk&usqp=CAU", "name": "Wagyu"}, {"icon": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQtNk7qbfHVbJkIrde4DFhTj7-acZupS0BMmA&usqp=CAU", "name": "Lamb"}]}
```

[image]

The Categories cannot show icon and name. Also I cannot got any error.

WHere has problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation, `categoryList` is not properly destructured from the component's props.

```js
export default function Categories({ categoryList }) {
 ...
}
```

You can learn more about JavaScript's destructuring assignment [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: opps....I missed that...

Answer (score 1):

You need to deconstruct `props` or call it from `props` object.

Option 1

```
export default function Categories(props) {

  return (

    <FlatList
     data={props.categoryList}
     ...
    />
  )
}
```

Option 2

```
export default function Categories(props) {
const { categoryList } = props;

 return (

    <FlatList
     data={categoryList}
     ...
    />
  )
}
```

Option 3

Provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78185086/7527762)